# Setting up IBM Cloud Log Analysis for Kubernetes (E0004)

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

I am using IBM Cloud.
I've created a Kubernetes cluster and deployed a simple app and I can see it running (see those console logs).  I've also provisioned an IBM Cloud Log Analysis service.  Both Kubernetes and Log Analysis are trial in case it matters.  I see some instruction to enable this Log Analysis so that the stdout and stderr gets sent to this Log Analysis.  Instruction URL is this:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/CloudLogAnalysis/tutorials/container_logs.html#container_logs
And I get to the part where I check my logging configuration of my cluster and I hit an error:

```
> ibmcloud cs logging-config-get <myCluster>
Retrieving cluster <myCluster> logging configurations... FAILED

Could not connect to a backend service. Try again later.   (E0004)
Incident ID: f2e3b033-e85c-4dc3-9d4e-7d20b8b8815f
```

And I thought maybe it's because I don't have any logging config.  So I tried to create one and still get very similar error:

```
> ibmcloud cs logging-config-create <myCluster> --logsource container --namespace '*' --type ibm --hostname ingest.logging.ng.bluemix.net --port 9091 --org <myOrg> --space dev
Creating logging configuration for container logs in cluster <myCluster>...
Validating space and org names...
FAILED

Could not connect to a backend service. Try again later.   (E0004)
Incident ID: 86f5c37c-2b11-477d-9417-b0a5bd2b170a
```

I am certain that my org name and space is correct.  What can possibly be the problem?

I've searched web and found that it could potentially be caused by lack of disk space.  Only type of disk space I have control that I know of is removing previous version of Docker image, so I've deleted them all except the one that's used, but I still have problem.

I've logged in using the CLI and issued a command like

```
ibmcloud target --cf
```

just to make sure that I am properly logged in and working at the right org and space before trying all these commands.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have a trial (free) Kubernetes cluster. To configure logging and monitoring, you must use a standard cluster in IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service. More info: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-health